# MVC Partial View with List

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-partialview

**Answered**

**Dbaseman was correct** but to simplify it all, I don’t need a modal and my code looks like this now:

```
[ChildActionOnly]
public ActionResult RecentNews()
{
    return PartialView(db.Articles.ToList());
}
```

and

```
@{Html.RenderAction("RecentNews");}
```

**Below is my old code that wasn’t working**

I’m having trouble getting the following to work, I’m unsure if I’m even close to being on the right track or not. The code all works fine if I create a View but not if I create a partial View and add it to other views. Whatever I try I seem to get  the error : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

In my view I have:

```
@Html.Partial("RecentNews")
```

My action looks like this:

```
public ActionResult RecentNews()
{
    var rn = (from m in db.Articles
                select new RecentNews
                {
                    ArticleHeading = m.ArticleHeading
                });
    return View(rn);

    //return View(db.Articles.ToList());
}
```

My modal:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace melbournesportsstadium.Models
{
    public class RecentNews
    {
        public string ArticleHeading { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And my RecentNews.cshtml:

```
@model List<melbournesportsstadium.Models.RecentNews>

<table>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ArticleHeading)
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

Can someone please help me get this working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting "null reference" because the partial view is not receiving any model; @Html.Partial doesn't return to the controller, it renders the view directly.  Change it to @Html.Action("RecentNews") and it should work.

Comment: Thanks dbaseman, I tried that and it sort of works but for some reason its pulling the partial view in as a complete view with the _layout. do you know why that would be???

Comment: @Bojangles Hm.  The only places I know of where a layout can be set are 1) in the View itself, 2) web.config in the view's path or a parent path

Comment: @Bojangles Sorry, I meant to write **_ViewStart.cshtml**.  Do you have one of those in you project?  A default layout might be set there ...

Comment: it was quite interesting but return PartialView and [ChildActionOnly] fixed it, thanks for your help!